# Proxy not working as expected when refresh the page or enter the proxy page on URL

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have deploy react frontend using docker compose and nginx. The nginx call to <kbd>backend:8080/api</kbd> for the data. Everything is working well, I have retrive data as expect.

Example: when I type on the browser URL <kbd>example.com</kbd> it will show up my page, using button on the page to navigate to <kbd>example.com/api/userlist</kbd> the page still there and I can collect the data as expect. But when I refresh or enter the URL <kbd>example.com/api/userlist</kbd>, it turn out there no html page instead of the raw json data only.

This issue only happen when I build into nginx. When I run with reactjs, this issue is not happening

## **More Information**

Here is my docker file for frontend

```
# Base image
FROM node:18.3.0-alpine AS build

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy source files
COPY . .

# Build application
RUN npm run build

# New base image
FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine

# Copy build files from previous stage
COPY --from=build /app/build/ /usr/share/nginx/html/

# start nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is my docker compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  frontend:
    build: ./front-end
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    depends_on:
    - backend
  backend:
    build: ./back-end
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

Here is my setting in nginx file

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

# Add root directory
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

# Add proxy for /api
location /api {
   proxy_pass http://backend:8080/api;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
}

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

It used to show the 404 error on reload, but when I add line <kbd>proxy_set_header Host $host;</kbd> it stop happen and this issue comeout

## I have try to

I have search for many place but seem like not to find out how to dead with this issue. somebody said that I should put <kbd>try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;</kbd> into the <kbd>location /api</kbd> block. But when I do that, it turn out I cannot call to backend to query any data.